Journal requires co-authors to register with ORCID, but if I don’t want to – what are my options?
Related but different:

Why would I want to register with ORCID?
Is there a benefit to registering digital identification via both ORCID and ResearcherID?

I'm a co-author on a submitted manuscript on research for which I made a significant contribution.
Note that I'm not looking to build an academic career or name for myself at this point in my life.
I received an email explaining the benefits of joining ORCID, and, as far as I understand, the message that if accepted, they will not publish it unless all authors join ORCID, providing it with the personal information they require so that ORCID can do the things with it they want to do with it, based on their privacy policies (present and future) and the visibility option I choose.
Since I contributed significantly to the research, it's not an option to remove my name. So it seems I have two options: register my information with an organization I may not want to register with, or tell the submitting author they must withdraw their submission.
Are those my only two options?
Note: Comments asking me for details why I might not want to register with ORCID will go unanswered; that's not the point of my question. Thanks.

Comments discussing the merit of OP's decision not to register with ORCID, and not to discuss the reasons for this, have been moved to chat. While a frame challenge might seem appropriate here, OP is specifically not interested in frame challenges, and this a well-scoped question that we can answer as-is. As always, please use the chat link above for further discussion; comments below this one should request clarification or suggest improvements to the question.

It would help us give better answers to your problem if you explained what the underlying issue is, and the reason you do not want to register with Orcid. This might be an XY problem. (@cag51 I don't think this comment breaks any rules; it is a request for clarification. Even if OP refuses to answer, it is still my right to ask.)

@FedericoPoloni: yes, but we’ve already had this conversation and OP’s answer was no. If you want to have this conversation again, please use the chat.

I understand not wanting to register with a third-party organization. What you might not realize is how very little information is needed to obtain an ORCiD. ORCID asks for an email address, which could even be a temporary email address such as you'd get at Temp Mail or Sharklasers. As for personal information, you're asked to provide "the [first] name you're usually known by". No family name is required; that's optional.
The page that asks for an affiliation appears to be the main stumbling block but down the bottom of that page there is a button that allows you to skip having to provide an affiliation.
Ultimately, you're providing

a (possibly temporary) email address that could be entirely anonymous
a first name as an identifier
a password


Providing minimal info could even be done in order to create throw away ORCID accounts for every submission requiring an ORCID (of course completely counteracting the intended purpose). However, strictly speaking this answer does not answer the question because it still involves registering with ORCID. It would be useful to know OP's motivation not to want an ORCID to see if what you write is an option for OP.

I will check again about the surname and affiliation being optional, I did not notice that. But I suppose once the ID is linked to the publication, that’s not so effective.

@uhoh, you can also deactivate your ORCID, see Deactivating an ORCID account. All personal information is said to be deleted, though some info must be kept because the ORCID can also be reactivated. I am not sure where a link in a paper to a deactivated ORCID will lead.

@Snijderfrey, Dilworth: "frame challenge answers" are still answers, and to my knowledge, are welcome.

If you completely refuse to register with ORCID even with minimal information or with a throw away account, then a journal strictly requiring you to do so is not the place to publish your research. However, you or the author handling the submission may still contact the publisher, explain the situation and hope that they will accept your position. It is quite obvious that either you or the publisher must take one step towards the other to resolve the conflict.

For the sake of this answer, I assume that the journal publicly states that having an ORCID is a requirement, in which case there are only the two options you mention, prima facie.
However, journals deviate from their rules all the time and tend not to list all the exceptions to streamline their processes and because exceptions are costly. The ORCID requirement is unlikely to be absolute, since if a paper has a deceased co-author without an ORCID, it’s impossible obtain a posthumous ORCID, and it would be a bad move for the journal to reject a manuscript for that reason. So, there possibly is a third option, which to convince the journal to drop their requirement for this particular paper.
Obviously, it helps if you have a compelling reason not to gain an ORCID, but it may also help if you can argue the publisher’s reasons for requiring an ORCID do not apply to you. If the journal doesn’t explicitly state its reasons, you can only make an educated guess, but one of the main advantages of ORCIDs for publishers is that, in the long run, they do not need to curate their own databases of authors, reviewers, etc. and do not need to manually resolve ambiguities in author names. For example, in a world where every journal requires ORCIDs, it’s easier to avoid soliciting reviews from a recent co-author or somebody who just happens to have the same name as an actual expert in the field. Also, ORCIDs can be used for logins etc. and thus simplify account management.
Now, if you have left academia or are about to, there is little chance that you will ever make a journal account, will build a relevant co-authorship network, are a likely reviewer, etc., which reduces the incentive for the journal to maintain a complete record for you. It may also help if your name is unique and likely to stay that way.

“… the journal publicly states…” It was said to me in a likely automatically generated email from the editor addressed to me. It’s a fair assumption.

It may well be a requirement and, as far as I’m concerned, it’s pretty legitimate.  ORCID is a non-profit and its mission is to uniquely identify authors.  This is not so much about you than about others properly giving credit to you as an author and not to someone else who may have the same or a similar name.  Not to put too fine a point on it, there might be lots of J. Smith working in a specific field.
So if you are really insistent not to participate, then create a burn account and give that number so at least someone else does not end up getting credit for your work.
I was senior editor at a journal where this was required because the journal deemed it essential to be able to reach all authors should some extraordinary circumstance come up.

Your last sentence makes a really important point - I had not thought about that. It's a good reason not to consider a "burn account".

I am curious: How would an ORCID help with contacting an author compared to an e-mail address of that author?

@Snijderfrey presumably authors update their ORCID information as they move through their careers: the email on file with the publisher may not longer be current.  Also some people may change names (in the case of marriages or separation for instances).

@ZeroTheHero, I am not convinced. My guess would be that the majority of ORCID accounts does not have any public e-mail address or is out of date. Especially those which you force on the authors.

@Snijderfrey I believe that publishers can have access to the email on file with ORCID.  I've always found it simpler to look up the most current institution and go from there.  It's not a do-all be-all solution but ORCID is gaining acceptance so maybe it will become something standard.

I'm not cheerleading for ORCID and was surprised to see how adamant some people were about insisting on this.  I suspect the manuscript tracking software uses some data from the ORCID profile.

@ZeroTheHero In Orcid, publishers can access a non-public email address only if (1) the address is marked as visible to trusted parties, and (2) the publisher has been added to your list of trusted parties. The data visibility is pretty clear also in the user interface.

@ZeroTheHero While many people likely don’t update their ORCID, at least they can. I have just been though a name change and am very happy to have had a minimal ORCID that I could get up to speed now. An email lacks the indirection to make that possible and may even be completely gone when changing names or affiliation.
